# AWS Elastic Beanstalk hosting PostreSQL on deployed EC2 server with Django

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm going through my first Elastic Beanstalk deployment. I have my application loading as I'd like it to. I now need to figure out how to auto deploy PostgreSQL with my deployment

I added the following to my requirements.txt `psycopg2==2.5.1`

It appears to have installed

```
$ psql --version
$ psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.5
```

settings.py in Django

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'database',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
}
```

These settings work perfectly before deployment, here is the error I'm getting after deployment:

`could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

I don't think I have to open up firewall settings for an EC2 instance to read it's own database, do I? Also because it's Django, everything should be auto created when the application runs.

Comment: Is the database filled with data from fixtures or dynamic data? If it's dynamic data then autoscaling groups are unlikely to work because instances are not aware of updates to others. Horizontally scaling PostgreSQL on the fly is damn hard. (I haven't found a workable solution yet)

Comment: from fixtures, should be blank columns pretty much. I expect for me to have to manually (or script) create the first admin user, but everything past that should be programmatically done via python webpages.

Comment: But then if you have an autoscaling group with 2 instances changes made on one instance will not be visible on the other instance. This appears to me as unwanted/unintended behavior of a database. Also when the group scales down to 1 instance all data on the other instance is lost.

Comment: Good info, I switched to RDS to prevent this from happening. we'll see if I can get it up and running :)

Comment: I got RDS up and running with minimal hiccups that Google / SO searching was able to fix. The only customization I had to do was for the first User of my Django application, which I could script, but manually adding is just as easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, using PostgreSQL on the EC2 server was a bad idea for dynamic data and scaling.

Used RDS for this purpose and it worked flawlessly.